# ObservableCollection in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Consider I have two classes.

Professor and TimePerDay.

```
 public class TimePerDay
{
    private ObservableCollection<TimeSpan> _subjTime;
    public ObservableCollection<TimeSpan> subjTime
    {
        get { return _subjTime; }
        set { _subjTime = value; } 
    }
}
private ObservableCollection<TimePerDay> _actualTime;
    public ObservableCollection<TimePerDay> actualTime
    {
        get { return _actualTime; }
        set { _actualTime = value; RaisePropertyChanged("actualTime"); }
    }
```

I'm trying to populate the TimePerDay class with each actualTime, my code is

```
                    ObservableCollection<TimePerDay> facultyTime = new ObservableCollection<TimePerDay>();
                    ObservableCollection<TimeSpan> ts = new ObservableCollection<TimeSpan>();
                    ts.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(9));
                    facultyTime.Add(new TimePerDay() { subjTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(2) });
```

and it's giving me error that An instance of type System.TypeSpan can not be assigned to a member of type System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection. How come it cannot assign a member while what I'm adding has a same type?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense.  What's `ts`?

Comment: In general, collection properties should not have setters.

Comment: @SLaks IIRC collection properties that are to be settable from XAML must have setters, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
facultyTime.Add(new TimePerDay() { subjTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(2) });
```

You are trying to create a new `TimePerDay` but are assigning a `TimeSpan` to `subjTime` which is an `ObservableCollection<TimeSpan>`. I suspect you want

```
facultyTime.Add(new TimePerDay() {
    subjTime = new ObservableCollection<TimeSpan> { TimeSpan.FromHours(2) }
});
```